# excel vba buttons in frame

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon,

I currently am having trouble figuring out how to get a frame that has 5 button options to assign a value to each button.  Ideally the buttons are tied to either a Strongly Agree, Agree, N/A, Disagree, Strongly Disagree option.

Secondly I don't know how to get the selected option with the frame to populate in a given table.

Ideally someone would answer questions 1 through 18 of my survey form and their options for all 18 questions are Strongly Agree, Agree, N/A, Disagree, and Strongly Disagree.  The answers for each question would be entered onto a "Data" table beginning on column F.

Any and all help is appreciated.  I have limited to no experience with vba and have been unable to find how to tackle this problem.  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What are you calling a `Frame`? Do you mean a `Group Box`? And when you say `Button` are you referring to an `Option Button`? Are you using `Active-X` objects or a `Userform`?

Comment: I am using a UserForm so my understanding of a "Frame" is what I've grouped them within using the toolbox option "Frame".  So that may very well be a Group Box, thank you.  I am also referring to an Option Button.  Sorry for the poor wording

Comment: Double-click the buttons, the VBE will create an event handler procedure for you. Happy exploration!

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/optionbutton/

Comment: Thank you for the help so far but that tip from @Mat'sMug doesn't help as I already know how to access the VBE for the button and gets me to where I currently am.  The link provided also doesn't answer my question as I am not trying to add or delete option buttons

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: So the options of strongly agree, agree, na, disagree, and strongly disagree are given for "each" question or once for "all" questions?

Comment: The given option buttons are given for each question.  Each question has a group of 5 option buttons.